# QGIS join data not transferring

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins

I'm reanalyzing data from a VA Late Woodland Palisaded Village. The site is mapped in CAD and exported as a shapefile. QGIS brings up the 1059 features as polygons. I am using a CSV file for the attribute data for the decorated pottery. I've joined the vector layer with the attribute file. All of the headings are there, but not all of the data is present.

It appears that where any feature has more than one entry, the attribute table stops at the first one. Is there a way to get it to list all of them?

The DB is organized into: Feature # in which not all have decorated pottery, ID# for each piece in each feature that has decorated pottery and then lists the various attributes. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a full list of all pieces with attributes and geographic information, do the joining the other way round: Join the attribute file with the vector layer using the `mmqgis`
 plugin.

This gives you as many polygons as pieces.

If you want to count the number of pieces within your polygons, you better calculate the centroids of the polygons with `Vector->GeometryTools->PolygonCentroid`, do the joining on that, and perform `Vector->Analysis->Points in Polygons` on the original vector layer and the joined data.

Comment: When I try to join, I get the following error message:Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/lyleebrowning/.qgis//python/plugins/mmqgis/mmqgis_dialogs.py", line 178, in browse_infiles
    header = reader.next()
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to open the file in universal-newline mode?

Comment: This might be operating-system-dependent. I saved the CSV with Libre Office, and got no such error; using Windows 7.